# array to string function can't work

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function like this:

```
function array2string($data) {
    if($data == '') return '';
    return addslashes(var_export($data, TRUE));
}
```

I invoke this function convert $_REQUEST Array to String just like

```
array2string($_REQUEST)
```

and convert the result String to Array use this function:

```
function string2array($data) {
    // print_r($data);
    $data=str_replace('\&apos;',"'",$data);
    // $data=str_replace('&apos;',"'",$data); // add by futan 2015-04-28
    $data=str_replace("\'","'",$data);
     // print_r($data);exit();
    if($data == "") return array();
    @eval("\$array = $data;");
    return $array;
}
```

Generally, it can work, bur sometimes,it doesn't work.
the result like this:

```
array (  \&apos;name\&apos; => \&apos;xxx
```

I cant find any problem, because I cant recurrence error.
someone can help me??

Comment: Whats the purpose of using these functions? You could use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` instead if you want string representation of the array data and vice versa.

Comment: Agree or even can use `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

Comment: @Ulver I want to save array in database as String.

Comment: Yes you should use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) for that purpose. I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: @Ulver I have used this function in my project , and many datas saved in database.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating your own custom function to get the string representation of the array/object and vice versa, you should use the PHP native [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) / [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) for that purpose:

```
// Serialize the array data. This string can be used to store it in the db
$serialised_string = serialize($_REQUEST);

// Get the array data back from the serialized string
$array_data = unserialize($serialised_string);
```

Also you could run into PHP injection issues by `eval()` usage in your custom function `string2array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative besides `serialize` would be to use `json_encode`:

```
 $array = ['foo' => 'bar'];
 $string = json_encode($array); // $string now has {'foo': 'bar'}

 // Restore array from string. 
 // Second parameter is passed to make sure it's array and not stdClass
 $array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Don't invent your function unless you absolutely need to. If you think you do, please add an explanation, why, so that we can help.